# Problem with broken mouthpiece of tube

Tags: medicine

I have some kind of facial product in tube container. The mouth piece of the tube has broken a little and now the cap is not fitting in it. There was a guideline written which said **to replace the cap tightly after use**. But now I can't fix the cap there since the mouth piece is broken. Is there any alternative for *replacing the cap*. [image]

Answer (score 3):

Press the tip of the tube into a marble-sized piece of modeling clay. The seal should be sufficient to preserve the product and the clay durable/malleable enough to continue use until the tube has been emptied.

Answer (score 3):

What type of facial product it is? If it is fluid, probably you can transfer into any other air tight container.

Comment: It is not fluid. It is gel. Please suggest an idea for that.